# Why is this bubblesort not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tuples, bubble-sort

I need to sort the following array by the 2nd element of the contained tuple. The process runs through, until the last element has passed. After that I get the exception

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Here is my used Code:

```
public list:Array<[string, number]> = new Array<[string, number]>();
//{["A", 0],["B", 8], ...}
...

var sorted = false
while (!sorted){
    sorted = true;
    this.list.forEach(function (element, index, array){
      alert(element);
      if (element[1] > array[index+1][1] ) {
        array[index][1] = array[index+1][1];
        array[index+1] = element;
        sorted = false;
      }
   });
}
```

I can't get, why this isn't working

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `Array.sort` ?

Comment: So you are going to have issues when you are at the last index....

Comment: the last `index + 1` does not exist. you may exit the last loop early.

Comment: You need to make sure you are not beyond the array limits when you compare with the next element.

Comment: @binariedMe he does

Comment: [debugging - How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
  array[index+1][1];
```

causes

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Thats because when the iteration reaches the last index, e.g `5`, it tries to take `6` from the array, which obviously does not exist. So you need to skip the last index while iterating, e.g.:

```
 if(array.length - 1 === index)
  return;
```

---

How i would do that:

```
 var sorted = false;

 while(!sorted){
   sorted = true;
   for(let index = 1; index < array.length; index++) {
      if(array[index][1] < array[index - 1][1]) {
       ([array[index], array[index - 1]] = [array[index - 1], array[index]]);
       sorted = false;
   }
 }
```

or much simpler:

```
 array.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
```